# How can i get the same tags of a list in R

Tags: r, list

How can i get the same tags of a list?

```
A<-list(a=10,b=15,a=20,b=5,c=10,a=5)
A$a
```

this would give me just the first "10" but i want all values from the tag "a"

Answer (score 1):

We can use `==` to get a logical vector and then extract the elements instead of `$` or `[[` because the key name is assumed to be unique and it matches the first element to extract 10

```
A[names(A) == 'a']
```